# How to make not scrollable listbox in windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, listbox

How do I make the listbox that can not scroll in windows phone 8?
it should not be even move up and down?

Comment: <ListBox Height="200" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
 - similar questions: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679326/wp7-prevent-listbox-scrolling) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557049/windows-phone-how-to-disable-touch-scrolling-in-scrollviewer-listbox)

Comment: @Romasz thank you very much man..stay blessed!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achive this you need to set  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" in your listbox control like below example:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lst" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                //add your data template here
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS -ms-touch-action: none;